# Selecting a Random Point Inside a Cube

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

> A point $P$ is selected at random inside a cube. Find the probability that $\angle APB \geq 135^o$, where $\overline{AB}$ is a body diagonal of the cube.

[image]

I am not able to come up with the right condition or the right variable to integrate. Geometrically, I think, $P$ has to move in a region which is an intersection of two spheres and the given cube. I am not able to visualise that out properly too.

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: it is a painful approach, but the condition $\alpha > 135$ is equivalent to $\cos\alpha < \cos 135$. And you can access $\cos\alpha$ through the scalar product.

Comment: @mookid I didn't get what you intend to do, could you please explain more?

Comment: You look for  $P(\alpha > 135)$. What I say is that it is $P(\cos\alpha < \cos 135)$. Now you can get $\cos\alpha = \frac{PA\cdot PB}{\|AP \| \| PB\|}$

Comment: It is very hard to setup the integral. If I didn't make any mistake, the integral is equal to

$$\frac{3\sqrt{3}\pi}{4}\int_0^1 (\sqrt{2-t^2}-1)^2\left( 1 - \frac{3}{\pi}\left( \theta(t) - \sin\theta(t)\cos\theta(t)\right) \right) dt$$
where 
$\theta(t) = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2-t^2}+1}{\sqrt{2}(1+t)}\right)$ over the interval $\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}-1}{3}, 1 \right]$ and zero otherwise.  
Numerically, I get something $\approx 0.38873583579811$ and this seems to match what I get by brute force MC simulation. I need more time to verify the details before I turn this into an answer.

Comment: @achillehui Won't the region satisfying this condition be the intersection of 2 segments of 2 different spheres and the cube?

Comment: @Pkwssis, No. the region is the intersection of the cube with a figure generated by rotating a "circular segment" along the diagonal. In certain sense, that figure is the intersection of infinite many spheres. Most part of that figure lies inside the cube. However, near the two vertices $A$ and $B$, a small piece of that figure get outside of the cube. That's the source of those horrible pieces $\theta(t) - \sin\theta(t)\cos\theta(t)$ in the integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WOLOG, consider the case where the cube is $[-1,1]^3$ and $A = (1,1,1)$, $B = (-1,-1,-1)$.

Let $P = (x,y,z)$ be any point inside the cube.
Let $\alpha$ be the angle $\angle APB$ and $r^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$, $s = x+y+z$.
We have

$$\begin{align}
\vec{PA}\cdot\vec{PB} &= (1-x)(-1-x)+(1-y)(-1-y) + (1-z)(-1-z) = - (3-r^2)\\
|\vec{PA}|^2 &= (1-x)^2 + (1-y)^2 + (1-z)^2 = 3+r^2 - 2s\\
|\vec{PB}|^2 &= (-1-x)^2 + (-1-y)^2 + (-1-z)^2 = 3+r^2 + 2s
\end{align}$$
The condition
$$\alpha \ge 135^\circ \iff \cos\alpha \le \cos135^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\quad\iff\quad\vec{PA}\cdot\vec{PB} \le -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\vec{PA}||\vec{PB}|
$$
leads to
$$\begin{align}
& 3-r^2 \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{(3+r^2)^2 - 4s^2}\\
\stackrel{*}{\iff} & 2(3-r^2)^2 - (3+r^2)^2 + 4s^2 \ge 0
\iff (r^2 - 9)^2 \ge 72 - 4s^2\\
\stackrel{*}{\iff} & 9-r^2 \ge 2\sqrt{18-s^2}
\iff r^2 \le 9 - 2\sqrt{18-s^2}\tag{*1}
\end{align}
$$
In above steps, the two marked $\stackrel{*}{\iff}$ is true because $3-r^2$ and $9-r^2$ are positive inside the cube.

Let $\Omega$ be the region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ determined by the last condition in $(*1)$
and $\mathcal{H}_t$ be the plane

$$\mathcal{H}_t = \big\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x+y+z = s = 3t \big\}$$

The intersection $\Omega \cap \mathcal{H}_t$ is a disk of radius $\rho(t)$ and

$$\rho^2(t) = r^2 - \frac{s^2}{3} = 9 - 2\sqrt{18-s^2} - \frac{s^2}{3}
\implies \rho(t) = \sqrt{3} ( \sqrt{2-t^2} - 1)$$

If $\Omega$ lies completely inside $[-1,1]^3$, then the probability we want will be

$$\begin{align}
\text{Prob}\;\stackrel{?}{=}\; &
\frac{1}{8}\int_{-1}^1 \pi \rho(t)^2 \sqrt{3} dt
= \frac{3\sqrt{3}\pi}{4}\int_0^1 (\sqrt{2-t^2}-1)^2 dt\\ 
=\; & \frac{(10-3\pi)\sqrt{3}\pi}{8}\approx 0.39125151339375
\end{align}\tag{*2}
$$
The problem is near the two vertices $A$ and $B$, small portions of $\Omega$ extend
beyond the cube $[-1,1]^3$. Following is a picture illustrating the geometry.

$\hspace0.8in$ [image: admissible region $\Omega$]

Let's consider what happens near $A$ where $t \sim 1$. If we intersect the cube $[-1,1]^3$
with the plane $\mathcal{H}_t$, 
$[-1,1]^3 \cap \mathcal{H}_t$ will be an equilateral triangle with centroid $(t,t,t)$. The mid points of the edges will be at a distance

$$\mu(t) = \sqrt{\frac32}\big(1-|t|\big)$$
from the centroid. When

$$\rho(t) > \mu(t) \quad\iff\quad |t| \ge \frac{2\sqrt{2}-1}{3}$$ 
the circle $\Omega \cap \mathcal{H}_t$ extend beyond the triangle $[-1,1]^3 \cap \mathcal{H}_t$. The portion outside the triangle is a union of 3 circle segments
centered at $(t,t,t)$. Let $2\theta(t)$ be the angle span by any one of these circle segments with respect to $(t,t,t)$. We have

$$\cos\theta(t) = \frac{\mu(t)}{\rho(t)} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac32}(1-|t|)}{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{2-t^2}-1)} = \frac{\sqrt{2-t^2}+1}{\sqrt{2}(1 + |t|)} $$

Elementary geometry tells us the area of any of these circle segments is
$$\rho(t)^2\big( \theta(t) - \sin\theta(t)\cos\theta(t)\big)$$

If we extend the definition of $\theta(t)$ so that it vanishes for $|t| < \frac{2\sqrt{2}-1}{3}$, we can modify $(*2)$ and get

$$
\text{Prob} 
= \frac{3\sqrt{3}\pi}{4}\int_0^1 (\sqrt{2-t^2}-1)^2 \left[1 - \frac{3}{\pi}\big(\theta(t)- \sin\theta(t)\cos\theta(t)\big)\right] dt
\tag{*2'}
$$
The difference between $(*2)$ and $(*2')$ is given by following expression

$$\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{4}\int_{\frac{2\sqrt{2}-1}{3}}^1 (\sqrt{2-t^2}-1)^2 \big(\theta(t)- \sin\theta(t)\cos\theta(t)\big) dt$$
I don't know how to integrate this analytically. Numerical integration gives us
a number $\approx 0.0025156775956542$ which is less than $1\%$ of that of $(*2)$. Finally, the probability we want is 
$$\bbox[8pt,border:1px solid blue]{
\text{Prob} \approx \frac{(10-3\pi)\sqrt{3}\pi}{8} - 0.0025156775956542 \approx 0.3887358357981
}
$$
As a double check, I have split the cube $[-1,1]^3$ into $300^3$ smaller cubes 
and count  the number of smaller cubes which satisfy $\cos\alpha \le \cos 135^\circ$. This gives me another estimate $\text{Prob} \approx 0.388734$.
This is consistent with what we have just calculated.